# How to deregister a service in linux through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, daemon

Can anyone please tell me how can I deregister a service once we uninstall the application?

This service is registered as part of installation of application.

This is the script I used to register service:

```
if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]  
then  
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  
fi


daemon --user=$OWNER sh .startScript.sh SERVICE true &
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your script seems to *start* the service, not to *register* it!

Answer (score 0):

It may depend upon the actual Linux distributions. Many of them are using (or are switching to) [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)

If you still use a `sysvinit` based Linux, consider copying `/etc/init.d/skeleton` to `/etc/init.d/yourservice` then edit that `/etc/init.d/yourservice` script. Also add appropriate symlinks (e.g. from `/etc/rc2.d/` etc...).

Comment: Hi, to be frank I don't have much knowledge about Linux OS, but currently am using CentOS 6.2 release.Really don't know which based Linux am using. Can you please let me know whether we achieve current issue through a script file.

Comment: As I wrote, if you have some `/etc/init.d/skeleton` file copy and adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: I don't have any such file like skeleton under /etc/init.d/

Comment: [root@localhost bin]# vim /etc/init.d/s  
sandbox         saslauthd       single          smartd          spice-vdagentd  sshd            sysstat